# How can I determine if a DataGrid has been sorted or paged, prior to the events being triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, events, datagrid

I have a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1zk1ey1.aspx) that has event handlers bound to [`SortCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.sortcommand.aspx) and [`PageIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.pageindexchanged.aspx).  How can I determine if those event handlers are about to be called, say on page_load?

These events will fire just fine after page_load, but I'd like to know at page_load if they are to be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` and `Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` will give the object causing the post back and the event argument. If the data grid does not cause the postback, then there is likely a value somewhere in the post. Use Fiddler to look at the request being sent when the button is clicked.